# Formatting Contents in RSS

Tags: rss, rss2

I'm making a RSS 2.0 feed powered by PHP & MySQL. I would like to know how to make simple formatting in the contents like **Line Breaks, Bold, Italics, Links, Images**.

When I try to insert a `<br>` in the database for a newline, the feed reader is displaying it as Invalid Feed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add line breaks in RSS feeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351107/how-to-add-line-breaks-in-rss-feeds)