# How to breakline in XML

Tags: xml, syntax

I am setting up an RSS feed, the way the XML is stored, as is common sense to anyone who knows a fair bit about xml or html, the white space is not preserved. I have done some research and not found any answers yet, but was wondering what the newline character is for XML. I.e the equivalent to a carriage return, `\n`, or `<br>`
Many thanks!

P.s. I am well aware this may be a dumb question.

Comment: Why do you need it? Anyway it's the common \n. <br> is a tag for html only.

Comment: When I display my RSS feed in a block on my page, there is no line between the end of one post and the start of the next, would ideally like to change that. That's why :)

Comment: @iKiar try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351107/how-to-add-line-breaks-in-rss-feeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CDATA section maybe? http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect

I've never used it for an RSS feed. But to illustrate, here's a CDATA newline:

```
<mytag><![CDATA[ here is
some text ]]></mytag>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the escape code **%0D%0A%**.