# Return (<br>) in description/ post

Tags: rss, cdata

How do I add a return (HTML `<br>`) in an RSS feed post?

I have been using `<![CDATA['<br/>']]>` but it doesn't seem to be supported by all systems!

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written to attempt this? What output or error messages are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351107/how-to-add-line-breaks-in-rss-feeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to make sure it doesn't get parsed by using

```
<![CDATA[' ']]>
```